# Get change value of color picker

Tags: angular

How to get color value once user pick any color.

want to store value in `firestore`.

using `ngx-color-picker`.

```
<input
        class="form-control ml-2 mr-2"
        [value]="color1"
        [style.background]="color1"
        [(colorPicker)]="color1"
        />
```

[example](https://zefoy.github.io/ngx-color-picker/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `colorPickerChange` event.

```
<input class="form-control" [value]="color1" [colorPicker]="color" [(colorPickerChange)]="updateFirestoreColor($event)/>
```

Comment: i tried this approch, getting error `Unexpected token '=' at column 29 in [updateFirestoreColor($event)=$event]`

Comment: It seems that you don't use the right syntax for binding event

Answer (score 0):

use `(colorPickerChange)="updateFirestoreColor($event)"` to get value.

```
<input
   class="form-control ml-2 mr-2"
   [value]="color1"
   [style.background]="color1"
   [(colorPicker)]="color1"
   (colorPickerChange)="updateFirestoreColor($event)"
/>
```

thanks @zooly for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is older, but I had this problem and found a better solution. Use **colorPickerClose** instead of **colorPickerChange**. This will emit an event only after picker is closed and not for every change detection.

```
<input class="form-control ml-2 mr-2"
    [value]="color1"
    [style.background]="color1"
    [(colorPicker)]="color1"
    (colorPickerClose)="updateColor($event)" />
```

and in ts file:

```
updateColor(event) {
  console.log(event); // this is your selected color
}
```